# Update Live Tile but which one is that?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an application with pinned secondary live tiles, they are showing days on the back of the tile and I would like to reduce the number of days each day. Now the problem is, that I don't want to change the other properties of the tile (so Title, Images, etc), only the content (a string) on the back: `FlipTileData.BackContent`
So I don't want to create new FlipTileData to pass that as a parameter for the Update method.

Second problem: How do I even know which tile is what I'm about to update?
I've tried this:

`foreach (ShellTile tile in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)` but tile has no attribute that gives me a help. Should I use NavigationUri to find out which tile is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this example [Working with Live Tiles in Windows Phone 7](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Working_with_Live_Tiles_in_Windows_Phone_7) and it should solve your problems.

Notice the `x.NavigationUri.ToString().**Contains("Title=SecondaryTile")**` on the code.

EDIT:

Combining a few lines of code from that website:

```
// modify Application Secondary Tile data
private void updateTile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    // get application specific tile - EXAMPLE
    ShellTile Tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("Title=SecondaryTileEXAMPLE_TITLE"));
    if (null != tile)
    {
        // create a new data for tile
        StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
        // tile foreground data
        data.Title = "Title text here";
        data.BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/Blue.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        data.Count = random.Next(99);
        // to make tile flip add data to background also
        data.BackTitle = "Secret text here";
        data.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/Green.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        data.BackContent = "Back Content Text here...";
        // update tile
        tile.Update(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any help there, because after that line the code shows creating a new data object for the updated tile. I would like to avoid that, I just need to change the BackContent, how is it possible?